# How to re-enable a disabled device

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a usb headset that, when installed, configured both the headphones and microphone. Because I wanted to continue using my 'line-out' connection for speakers i clicked the 'disable this device' for the headset's speakers. That worked but now I can't find how to re-enable those headphones.

thx

Comment: It might be helpful to know *where* you clicked this "disable the device" button, if you can remember.  I'm pretty sure there's a few different places this can be done.

Comment: Originally had clicked the icon that shows at the top of the Notificaiton's volume scale (L-Click). I've followed M'vy's solution and have re-enabled the headset but find that i can not reproduce that original click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>R-Click</kbd> Show deactivated devices

On the device 
<kbd>R-Click</kbd> Activate

EDIT: BTW it is in the playback devices menu from the sound icon in notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to device manager >view >show hidden devices. Then you should be able to go to the desired device and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several options, and what seemed to have worked was:
Device manager
[R+click] {Sound Blaster Tactic...etc. - my USB device}
[L+click] {Scan for hardware changes}
Then I quickly disconnected from USB and plugged into a different slot, hoping I could re-introduce the parties to each other, fresh start y'know.

Answer (score 0):

So what you do is Right click the Volume button on the bottom right side of your computer.
  Then go to **"Volume Control Options"**. From there you it will show you the devices that are listed.

But if you notice it won't say where the **"Disable Device"** are.  Now, Right Click in that box and there should be an option to **"Enable or Show Devices"** that's how you'll be able to see your USB headset to then Right Click and **"re-enable"** that device.
Hope this helped